# Unable to get post form using rest api

Tags: java, html, spring, rest

I have a method, that is supposed to call html form and then add use info from it in another function. But when I call http request like this `localhost:8080/stops/addStop` I get blank page("/stops" is passed to @RequestMapping at class declaration).
Here is my method:

```
@PostMapping("/addStop")
    public String addStop(@RequestParam String stopName) {
        try {
            stopsDao.insertStop(new Stops(stopName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return "redirect:/stops";
    }
```

And that's like my form looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Add stop</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="/stops/addStop">
    <label for="stop">Stop:</label>
    <input type="text" id="stop" name="stop"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have already tried to find the answer to this problem, but none of them helped. I will be happy to get any advice on it.

**Update**
It might be obvious for some, but took some time for me, so I will leave the answer here. If I want to show the page, I can use  `@GetMapping`(might be some ways to do it using only @Post, but I couldn't find anything on it).
So the following code for showing the page should look like:

```
@GetMapping("/addStop")
public String showAddStopForm(Model model) throws IOException {
     String formHtml = Files.readString(Path.of("lab-1/src/main/resources/templates/stops.html")); //Path to your html file
     return formHtml;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.